# No type or protocol named 'UIUserActivityRestoring'

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having the following error:

```
No type or protocol named 'UIUserActivityRestoring'
```

The code where the error is happening

```
   [self application:application continueUserActivity:activity restorationHandler:^(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable restorableObjects) {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having been searching on the internet and nothing found.
I decided to update my Xcode 9.4 to Xcode 10, same version as my colleagues
This solved my problem.